# Is it necessary to house or enclose magnetic hard drives when they are running?

Tags: hard-drive, enclosures

I'm building a DIY NAS, and I'm looking for a solution to physically arrange the hard drives together. I've seen products like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Icy-Dock-Vortex-MB074SP-B-3-5-inch/dp/B00GSQMYY0/ref=cm_cd_al_qh_dp_i), and I'm wondering if they are actually suitable for long term operation.

[image: drive cage]

I know you're not supposed to run a magnetic hard drive just placed on a desk, or something, because the motion generated by the rotations might be problematic if it's directly absorbed back into the drive. Another thing a traditional case provides is shielding from dust from the environment; but I think hard drives are fairly shielded anyway.

Comment: well thats a cooler, not a nas. a nas will contain a OS with a lot more features that you could need to run your nas. whats really important when having a nas is the hard drive, you want something reliable taht runs 24h without any problems. usually on the WD side, the red series will give you what you need

Comment: Yes, I understand that - I'm looking for a way to arrange the hard drives safely physically and then I'll build the NAS components around it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the question:

> Is it necessary to house or enclose magnetic hard drives when they are running?

No, it is not neccesary.  The drives will work as long as they as provided with power and with a data connection to the disk controller.

> I'm building a DIY NAS, and I'm looking for a solution to physically arrange hard drives together. I've seen products like this, and I'm wondering if they are actually suitable for long term operation.
>
> I know you're not suppose to run a magnetic hard drive just placed on a desk or something because the motion generated by the rotations might be problematic if it's directly absorbed back into the drive. Another thing a traditional case provides is shielding from dust from the environment; but I think hard drives are fairly shielded anyway.

According to [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_failure#Metrics_of_failures), high temperatures were not well correlated with disk failures in a large sampling.  In addition, dust is common in almost all applications since, if the inlets are filtered, they are rarely done so with a filter that will filter fine particles.

So, I would say pick whatever enclosure (in no particular order):

1. Looks good (we like our custom builds to look nice)
2. Is easy to get the drives in and out of.
3. Provides a clean way to wire the drives.
4. Fits with your other components.

Comment: What about concerns regarding vibrations and not being bolted into a heavy case that will dampen them?

Comment: Actually I have seen many enclosures that made no attempt to hard tie the drive to the chassis.  Hot plug chassis slide the drive in and out.  And if the drive is hard secured it is generally only on the axis towards the connector.

Comment: It is true that the google study cited by that wikipedia article reported little correlation between drive temperature and failure rates. However the study was in a data centre environment so the vast majority of drives studied were cool. Furthermore the study trusted drive's self-reported temperature so a drive-model that misreported temperature could easily have skewed the results.